# How to plot a txt data in a shape file in R?

Tags: r, shapefile

i have a txt data where each line is one lightning with lat, lon and intensity, i want to plot this upper a shapefile (polygon).

I cant read the shapefile, and i dont know how to plot the data upper the shapefile, anyone can help me? Maybe with some idea ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `sp` is your friend here.

```
library(sp)

data(meuse)

str(meuse)

coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x + y
plot(meuse)
```

You could also could give package `sf` a try. See [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html).

Comment: i got sucessul in ploting the data ! thanks. But how can i plot this on the shape file? how i read and plot both?

Comment: @MatheusRegis have you tried searching the internet on how to read in a `.shp` file? For instance: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/how-to-open-a-shapefile-in-r